# ImageView doesn't working on CardView on the build of an android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-cardview

I'm learning to do an apps for android on android studio and I'm stucked on 1 problem.
I added ImageView on the CardView. On preview I can see ImageView, but on the build I can't. How to fix it?

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView2"
                android:layout_width="393dp"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/da"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[15]" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="210dp"
                        android:layout_height="99dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="@string/tri"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65999997" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="385dp"
                android:layout_height="134dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48000002">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="249dp"
                        android:layout_height="109dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="@string/b"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/da"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main_activity is empty :D

What I've expected
https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/12/24/eae2df1528a0b3949d7daf1bf82132d1-full.jpg

What I've got
https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/12/24/8c78dd0e5a98d622a429a08bca14c8bb-full.jpg

Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I can't find a solution at google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Make this**

```
tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[15]"
```

**To This:**

```
 app:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[15]"
```

Actually, Add a different drawable because these avatars are only for the sample version not for, the build version.

**To avoid this**

*AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute srcCompat (attr) reference [weak].*

**Use a drawable**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

do this to your imageview

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

put image in `res/drawable`